# Is a cycle composed of two primitive cycles from different equivalent classes also primitive?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, zeta-functions

Suppose we have two primitive cycles $C_1$ and $C_2$ which belong to two different equivalence classes.
Is the cycle $C_1 C_2$ also primitive?

My intuition is that this cycle is also primitive, but I fail to compose a proof—I could not find a direct contradiction by making the proposition false.

---

This question is raised in the context of the [zeta function of a finite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ihara_zeta_function), and primitive cycles have the usual meaning.
In case that terminology should be fixed, related definitions are listed below.

- A **walk** is just represented by a sequence of arcs (directed edges).
- A walk is **closed** if it starts and ends with the same vertex.
- A walk is **non-backtracking** if it does not have a subsequence like $\{i \to j, j \to i\}$.
- A **cycle** is a walk which is closed and non-backtracking.
- A cycle is **primitive** if it is not obtained by repeating another cycle $m>1$ times.
- Two cycles are said to be **equivalent** if one can be obtained by the cyclic permutation (i.e.,  reselecting the starting vertex) of another.
- By this equivalence relation, cycles can be classified into different equivalence classes.
  In particular, primitive cycles can be classified into classes and these classes of primitive cycles are used to define the zeta function of a finite graph.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $C_1C_2$ doesn't even have to be non-backtracking....

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, my notation does not forbid non-backtracking, but I presumably not include such a case. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:
\begin{align*}
C_1\colon 0\to a\to b\to 0 \to c\to d\to 0\to a\to b\to 0 \\
C_2\colon 0 \to c\to d\to 0\to a\to b\to 0 \to c\to d\to 0
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for this illustrative counterexample. Now I know which ingredient is missing to have a true proposition — there should be no cycle having shorter length than $C_1$ or $C_2$. Could you elaborate this in the answer?

Comment: I have elaborate this in my long comment (as "an answer"). Now there is no need to bother you. I hope it could be helpful for someone. :-)